# Using a pipe filter, to make it work on several conditions

Tags: angular, filter, pipes-filters

I have a pipe filter, that filters the list of my clients by `name`. I need to add another filter, so the clients could be filtered by `account_number` The filter pipe:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter',
  pure: false
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], term): any {
    return term ? items.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) != -1) : items;
  }

}
```

In my view, I bind the filter in the way like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="term" [(ngModel)]="term">
<input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Account number"> <!--Here I want to make another ngModel-->

<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let client of clients | filter: term | sortBy: 'id'; let i = index"
    <td>{{client.name}}</td>
    <td>{{client.account_number}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So, do I need to make another `pipe` for filtering by a different property, or can it be done in a single `pipe`? Also, if it will be two different pipes, how should I include it to the filter in the view? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with single pipe try this

```
 transform(values: any[], filter: string): any {
    if (!values || !values.length) return [];
    if (!filter) return values;

    filter = filter.toUpperCase();

    if (filter && Array.isArray(values)) {
      const keys = Object.keys(values[0]);
      return values.filter(v => v && keys.some(k => v[k].toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) >= 0));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting an error: `ERROR TypeError: v[k].toUpperCase is not a function`

Comment: It doesn't matter what I type in the input, whether it's a string or a number, I get the same error.

Comment: can post sample data of your array

Comment: The array looks like:`[{name: "Alex", account_number: 123}, {name: "Bob", account_number: 456}]` and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151266/discussion-between-arun-kumaresh-and-alex-zakruzhetskyi).